# tocloft package linking list of figure/tables to the wrong page

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I am using Masters/Doctoral Thesis class, by Vel and Johannes Böttcher. I downloaded it from here: http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis

The class has an option, `liststotoc`, to add the list of figures/tables/etc to the table of contents. And it works fine.

However, when using `tocloft` package -which I need to change the style of toc-, the list of figures and of tables disappear from the toc. And the lists themselves appear right under the toc instead of on a new page.

And while I fixed the mentioned issues by using `\newpage` ,`\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}` and `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}` instead of `liststotoc`, clicking on those two items in the toc leads to the page of the item that is above them in the toc. In this case to the page of "Acknowledgement" numbered **iv**, instead of their respective pages at **vii** and **viii** ', even though that the page numbers next to them in the toc are correct.

And if there is no item above the list of figures and list of tables in toc, clicking on any of the two in toc will send me back to the beginning of the document.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside, english, singlespacing]{MastersDoctoralThesis} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex} % Use the bibtex backend with the authoryear citation style (which resembles APA)

\addbibresource{example.bib} % The filename of the bibliography

\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} % Required to generate language-dependent quotes in the bibliography

\usepackage{fontspec} % Fonts package
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{tocloft} % Modify toc package

%-----------------------------------
%   MARGIN SETTINGS
%-----------------------------------

\geometry{paper=a4paper, inner=2.5cm, outer=3.8cm, bindingoffset=.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm}

%-----------------------------------
%   THESIS INFORMATION
%-----------------------------------

\thesistitle{.}
\supervisor{.}
\examiner{}
\degree{.}
\author{.}
\addresses{}

\subject{.} 
\keywords{}
\university{\href{.}{.}}
\department{\href{.}{.}} 
\group{\href{.}{.}}
\faculty{\href{.}{.}}

\AtBeginDocument{
\hypersetup{pdftitle=\ttitle} 
\hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authorname} 
\hypersetup{pdfkeywords=\keywordnames}
}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter % Use roman page numbering style (i, ii, iii, iv...) for the pre-content pages

\pagestyle{plain} % Default to the plain heading style until the thesis style is called for the body content

%-----------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%-----------------------------------

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
TITLE TEXT
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

%-----------------------------------
%   ABSTRACT PAGE
%-----------------------------------

\begin{abstract}
\addchaptertocentry{\abstractname}
ABSTRACT TEXT
\end{abstract}

%-----------------------------------
%   ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS
%-----------------------------------

\begin{acknowledgements}
\addchaptertocentry{\acknowledgementname} % Add the acknowledgements to the table of contents
ACKNOWLEDGMENT TEXT\ldots
\end{acknowledgements}

%-----------------------------------
%   LIST OF CONTENTS/FIGURES/TABLES PAGES
%-----------------------------------

\newpage
\tableofcontents % Prints the main table of contents

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures % Prints the list of figures

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\listoftables % Prints the list of tables


\end{document}
```

Thank you.

Comment: never use fontenc and inputenc packages with luatex or xetex

Comment: Use \phantomsection before the \addcontentsline,  so that there is an anchor for the link. And unrelated: better use the biber backend with biblatex.

Comment: Thank you @UlrikeFischer, that solution worked perfectly, much appreciated. Thank you as well David for the info.